# Trying to retrieve first rows partition by offer_id

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

Suppose I have a table with columns

body | offer_id | created_at

I need to group them by offer_id, order by created_at and then retrieve first row in this table. I am now using the following logic

```
select first_value(M.body) over (partition by M.offer_id order by M.created_at ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING), 
        (select created_at 
         from quotes_site.offers O 
            where O.id = M.offer_id) as crt

from quotes_site.messages M
    where M.created_at between '2016-01-01' and '2016-02-01'
```

Although there is no error, the query runs indefinitely so I assume there must be something wrong. I am also not very familiar with the frame clause so more detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated

P.S. Server runs on AWS Redshift

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how many rows are returned by the sub-select (crt) and how many distinct offer_id?

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest row_number():

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.offer_id,t.body,t.created_at,s.created_at,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.offer_ID ORDER BY t.created_at) as rnk
    FROM quotes_site.messages t
    INNER JOIN quotes_site.offers s
    ON(s.id = t.offer_id))
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `distinct on` instead:

```
select distinct on (M.offer_Id), M.*, o.created_at as o_created_at
from quotes_site.messages M left join
     quotes_site.offers O
     ON  O.id = M.offer_id
where M.created_at between '2016-01-01' and '2016-02-01'
order by M.offer_id, M.created_at;
```

Comment: I figured I could do that, but I am also trying to learn how to use over partition by capabilities in sql

Comment: @EduardKim Your question is correctly answered here. If you only want solutions using window functions then say so in the question so people do not squander their time.